# Centos 7 and MariaDB - Can't create triggers

Tags: mariadb, nagios, centos7

I'm using Centos 7 and MariaDB but I have problem creating triggers:

create trigger chu after update on nagios_hoststatus for each row begin replace into events.e select new.host_object_id, now(); end;

create trigger csu after update on nagios_servicestatus for each row begin replace into events.e select new.service_object_id, now(); end;

This error is what I get: multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table

Any solution ?

Comment: If you need multiple triggers of the same type on a single table, you must combine them into a single trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have to FIRST drop trigger in order to create a new one with the same name :) Command is "DROP TRIGGER *name_of_trigger"

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, get sure you've removed it before create again using

```
DROP TRIGGER [IF EXISTS] [schema_name.]trigger_name
```

and then

```
CREATE TRIGGER ....
```

Now if you have some other trigger you have to merge code from both triggers into one, then drop existing trigger, and then create a new one.

To show the list of existing triggers use SHOW TRIGGERS.

```
SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE `table` = 'companies';
```